# Using Html::anchor of FuelPHP code in Twig Template

Tags: php, twig, fuelphp

I have the below line of code in the FuelPHP view file (php) and I am converting the project code from PHP template to TWIG template engine.

```
<?php echo Html::anchor('quiz/edit/'.$quiz->id, 'Edit'); ?>
```

How can I convert the below line of code to work with TWIG template?

I tried the below thing in the .php file:

```
$data['edit_url']=  Html::anchor('quiz/edit/'.$quiz->id, 'Edit');
```

And in .twig file, I use the below line:

```
{{edit_url}
```

With this I get the HTML code as a text(without hyperlink) as the html is escaped to normal text by default.

What I was expecting is a URL hyperlink without being escaped.

**Note:** I tried the below code and I get NULL out of it.

```
$data['edit_url']= Router::get('quiz/edit/',array('id' => $quiz->id));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FuelPHP parser for Twig makes a lot of Fuel helpers available using a Twig extension.

Check the `./classes/twig/fuel/extension.php` file in the Parser package to see which ones. Html::anchor is included too.

Comment: Wow.. That was really useful. I solved some other issues based on this. I used this and it works for me. Thanks. {{ html_anchor('quiz/edit/' ~ quiz.id, 'Edit') }}